# Поиск в строке

Tags: регулярные-выражения

И снова здравствуйте. Ткните носом на статью, объясните или скажите в какую сторону искать, как в строке, при помощи регулярных выражений, найти что-то что идет после чего-то и перед чем-то. К примеру, как в строке

```
Три странных дятла пилили дятла дятлом для бритья дятлов
```

найти 'дят' в каком-то слове, которое должно идти после слова 'дятла' и перед 'для'? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WIKI: Регулярные выражения: просмотр вперед и назад`](http://goo.gl/yxge0)

Comment: Оно. Спасибо.